# How to check outcome of unattedned SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installation?

Tags: windows, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm creating deployment project for a software suite which needs SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition. I've created working installation config & script that lets me install it in quiet mode (unattended install) - and tested, that if prerequisites are installed, SQL Server installs without a problem (on a testing system).
The problem is: if I install SQL Server in unattended mode, I won't get any errors if e.g. Powershell is missing, the installation will just abort without prompt.
Is there a way I would be able to test if it was successful OR to get any information about errors that happend, but in scope of classic command prompt? It already happened that powershell was not installed on a machine I was trying to deploy the server on.

Comment: I am also very keen to know this.  I have an existing NSIS installer which installed SQL2005 and was able to check return codes. But this functionality seems to have been lost in 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an NSIS installer script which installs SQL 2008 R2 Express and is able to do this.
The sql "setup.exe" file uses a return code of 0 to indicate success.

Note that if you are using a file which requires an initial step of extracting setup files (SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe for example), then I recommend extracting these yourself and calling setup.exe directly.
These files can be extracted by using the "-x" command line param.
(ie SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe -x)